# Ubuntu not recognizing rails after successfull installation, using zshrc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, zshrc

I'm using ubuntu, zshrc, and after installing rails, using

```
gem rvm all do gem install rails
```

and getting a successful install, i'm getting a

```
zsh: command not found: rails
```

I'm guessing this has to do with my ~/.zshrc file

I have this at the end of it:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

I'm a noob at understanding how paths work, any idea how to get terminal to recognize rails commands?

Comment: Are you sure it gets installed? the `gem rvm all` command seems weird to me.

Comment: I had the same problem, but it seems to be profile loading issue... I get around it by just switching to my user account... from my user account... This is, if I am `user`, I open a terminal and type `su - user`... Then the profile loads fully

Comment: try: `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` and `gem install rails`

Comment: hm, none of those seemed to work for me, yes it tells me after running the command that rails is installed, none of the commands are working though

Comment: just had to uninstall zshrc and go back to bash...